# Why are my system preferences not saved when changing file associations?

Tags: linux-mint, kate, libreoffice

Every time I open a .csv file it tries to open in LibreOffice Calc which I don't want it to, so I changed the default program to Kate, and it updates the system preferences. But then the next time I open a .csv file (even the same one) it goes back to trying to open it in LibreOffice.

Is there a better way to update the file associations, or to stop LibreOffice overriding my preferences?

I'm running Linux Mint 15, Olivia.

Thanks.

Comment: A better way than what?

Comment: @mikeserv: Well the way I'm doing it is right-clicking on the file, -> open with -> choose program -> remember association for file type -> ok.  This doesn't work.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Probably there are many ways, whether they'd be better I don't know, but I suspect the most universal would be with *`xdg-utils`.* Still I don't think that's the cause of your problem - I assume you're using the Cinammon desktop environment in Mint, which is Gnome based, and you're trying to associate a file with Kate - a KDE app - so it might be they just don't like each other. That's already more than I know on the subject, but maybe it will give you a feeling of what to poke at.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.  I edited `~./local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and changed any instances of `libreoffice-calc.desktop` that I didn't want (all the .csv related ones) with `kate.desktop`.